# Closing information for bounty sent too soon

Tags: bug, bounty

I just got a message in my SO-inbox that my [most recent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720685/safe-term-order) bounty is over, yet the page claims that there are still 10 minutes left - yes I did a reload..

To clarify, this is what I thought in reaction to it:

- some js related problem with my mobile connexion
- browser cached an old version, reload
- the question page is out of date
- the message is coming from a server with a broken time sever - those frequently happen to be ahead of time

Comment: I don't get it, you want the email to be sent the exact moment the bounty expires?  Giving you -20 seconds to read it?

Comment: @HansPassant: Yes. I expect an e-mail to arrive at the point in time the very e-mail claims to arrive. Not before that. There are many out-of-sync issues already with slow connections.

Comment: This web site is run by people that set their alarm clock to a time *before* they are due to arrive at work.  The equipment has little to do with it.

Comment: @HansPassant - do you disagree that it's unexpected for a user to receive an email notifying them that something has happened when that thing has not actually happened yet?

Comment: My opinion matters very little, I just expect SE staff to make sane decisions.  They have a pretty good track record.